# Nasm ld relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_16

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, linker-errors

I'm an assembly newbie,
my code looks like this:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    call print_string
    .inf_loop:
    hlt
    jmp .inf_loop

print_string:
    cld
    mov si, string
    .loop
    lodsb
    cmp al, BYTE 0
    je .done
    out 0xe9, al
    jmp .loop
.done
    ret

; The stivale header our kernel needs to be booted via limine
section .stivale2hdr
    ; This is set to zero, so the bootloader will use the elf entry point
    entry_point: dq 0
    ; This tells the bootloader where our stack is
    ; Remember the stack grows downwards :)
    stack: dq this_is_the_stack+8192 
    flags: dq 011b
    tags: dq 0


section .bss
    align 16
    this_is_the_stack: resb 8192

section .rodata
    string: db "Hello, world!", 0
```

Then I'm assembling with:
`yasm --arch=x86 --oformat=elf64 --machine=amd64`

And linking with this:
`ld -Tlinker.ld -nosdtlib -zmax-page-size=0x1000 -static --no-dynamic-linker -ztext`

Ld gives me the following errors:

```
./arch/x86_64/boot.o: in function `no symbol':
arch/x86_64/boot.S:(.text+0xb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_16 against `.rodata'
make: *** [Makefile:29: kernel.elf] Error 1
```

What could I change to fix this?
Do you need to see my linker script?

Comment: NASM may need `default rel` and `lea rsi, [string]` or `lea rsi, [rel string]` instead of `mov si, string` (the `lea` is needed to use `rip`-relative addressing, the `rel` indicates to enable the same, and you should use `rsi` not `si`). Not sure whether YASM has the exact same syntax or slightly different.

Comment: Wait a second, is this code supposed to run in 16-bit real mode, or 64-bit long mode, or what?

Comment: @ecm: YASM has identical syntax to NASM for this, and for instructions in general.  It might sometimes differ in choice of how to encode (e.g. `mov r64,imm64` for `mov reg,symbol` from NASM, but YASM choosing sign_extended_imm32 without `strict qword`, for that case which normal code shouldn't use in the first place because 64-bit absolute addresses are inefficient.)